# Wait for async blocks completion

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

For example I have a method with three async blocks. Each block result is needed to perform next block to achieve final methods result. So, what I'm looking for is a nice GCD strategy to make'em perform in a strict order and without dead locks

```
__block id task1Result;    
__block id task2Result;    
__block id finalResult;  

[self startTask1:^(id result) { task1Result = result }]  

[self startTask2:task1Result block:^(id result) { task2Result = result }]  

[self startTask3:task2Result block:^(id result) { finalResult = result }]
```

**UPD.** I have found a solution:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

__block id task1Result;    
__block id task2Result;    
__block id finalResult;  

[self startTask1:^(id result) { 
  task1Result = result;
  dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
}];  
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

[self startTask2:task1Result block:^(id result) { 
  task2Result = result;
  dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
}];  
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

[self startTask3:task2Result block:^(id result) { finalResult = result }];
```

But in my case I faced a problem with some library method which brings app to deadlock. ><

Comment: Don't use semaphores.  That is the worst possible solution as it can easily lead to priority inversion.  Please make use of a serial queue to serialize your operations.

Comment: Can you give me an example code of how should I make use of them in my case ?

Comment: Create a serial queue, and submit your blocks to it.  They will be executed in order.  dogsgod gave you an example below.

Comment: But dispatch_async wont wait for a child blocks completion in his example, as far as I know.. Am I wrong ?

Comment: dispatch_async will return to the caller immediately.  dispatch_sync will return to the caller only after the block has executed.  A serial queue ensures that all blocks are executed sequentially and not in parallel.  Do you care about the calling thread blocking until the block has executed?  If so, use dispatch_sync.  Do you care that blocks are only executed in order?  If so, use a serial queue.  Based on the question, three async operations that need to execute in order, dispatch_async with a serial queue is indicated.

Answer (score 3):

Create a serial dispatch queue like described here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

In a nutshell:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    printf("Do some work here.\n");
});
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    printf("When finished do next task.\n");
});
```

Be aware that you have to handle the queue yourself.

Comment: A dispatch_queue is nice, but if he's calling asynchronous APIs inside the dispatch_async, it'll get him no closer to the goal of awaiting all his API calls.

Comment: @Claus Jørgensen: The queue is serial and will take care of executing one task at a time. Could you elaborate why this would not be enough?

Comment: If you put `dispatch_async(anotherQueue, ^{})` inside your `dispatch_async` it'll not wait for it to finish. Assuming his task API is a existing one not built on GCD, your suggestion will have no impact. It comes down to whether the OP is calling a existing API or not.

Comment: Thanks for clarification didn't think of non GCD stuff

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I don't think we need to consider other APIs here as the question is pertaining to dispatch.  dogsgod is right that the correct solution is to use a serial queue.

Answer (score -1):

If each task directly consumes the result of the previous task, can’t you start each one from the completion callback of its predecessor? You’ll still need a dispatch group to wait for the last task to complete, though.

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
__block id result;

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self startTask1:^(id task1Result) {
  [self startTask2:task1Result block:^(id task2Result) {
    [self startTask3:task2Result block:^(id finalResult) {
      result = finalResult;
      dispatch_group_leave(group);
    }];
  }];
}];

dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

One complication you may run into is whether attempting to enqueue tasks from a completion handler runs the risk of deadlock, i.e. if your completion handlers are invoked on the same serial queue that handles enqueueing tasks.

Comment: This way is too ugly. I want to get rid of it.

Comment: Do you find it ugly primarily because of the nesting of completion handlers?